# task.Task undefined (type entities.Task has no field or method Task)

Tags: go

```golang
package entities

type Task struct {
    Id       int64
    task     string
    assignee string
    deadline string
    action   string
}
```

```golang
package taskcontroller

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/jeypc/go-crud/config/entities"
)

func Index(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    temp, err := template.ParseFiles("config/views/task/index.html")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    temp.Execute(response, nil)
}

func Add(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    if request.Method == http.MethodGet {

        temp, err := template.ParseFiles("config/views/task/add.html")

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        temp.Execute(response, nil)

    } else if request.Method == http.MethodPost {

        request.ParseForm()

        var task entities.Task

        task.Task = request.Form.Get("task")
        task.Assignee = request.Form.Get("assignee")
        task.Deadline = request.Form.Get("deadline")

        fmt.Println(task)

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `Task` struct defines a field called `task` (all lower case). You are trying to access it using `.Task` (starting with upper case). Go identifiers are *case sensitive*. `task` != `Task`.

Comment: Also note that identifiers starting with lower-case letters or the underscore are considered *unexported*, which means that they can NOT be accessed outside of the package in which they were declared. This means that, if `t` is an instance of an *imported* type, then `t.f` is illegal, but `t.F` is legal (as long as `F` is a field or method of `t`).

Comment: change the field to `Task`. It's not exported, and therefore cannot be accessed outside of the `entities` package

Comment: change like what?

Comment: @AM capitalize it. `type Task struct {` then the field `task string` should be `Task string`. That way you'll be able to set `task.Task`.  you'll have to do the same thing for all fields in the type (assignee, deadline) that you're trying to access outside of the entities package

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this is probably going to get closed, as this is a simple typo, or just a case of RT(f)M. I'd recommend you walk through the golang tour. Exported names is something explained on [page 3 of the *basics*](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3), so pretty much at the start of the tour. If you haven't looked at the tour at all, [the tour starts here](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1)

Still, I'll answer your question using your specific code:

In golang, capitalisation matters. In your case, you have a package called `entities`, in which you define the type `Task`, with a capital T. Because you're using a capital as the first character of the name, the type is *exported*. When you `import` the `entities` package in your `taskcontroller` package, you'll be able to use `entities.Task`. Had you written:

```
package entities

type task struct {}
```

you would **not** be able to write `t := entities.task{}`. To put it in *conventional* OOP terms: any name beginning with a lower-case character is private. If they start with an upper-case character, they are public.

Now looking at your type:

```
type Task struct {
    Id       int64
    task     string
    assignee string
    deadline string
    action   string
}
```

You have a public type called `Task`, with 5 fields. One field (`Id`) is public, and can be accessed outside of the `entities` package. The other four fields are *private*, and can only be accessed from inside the `entities` package.

Now, you're trying to set fields like `assignee`, `task`, and so on in the `taskcontroller` package. You can't do that, because they are *private*. To be able to access these fields, the simplest way is to change the `entities.Task` type and make the fields public:

```
type Task struct {
    Id       int64
    Task     string
    Assignee string
    Deadline string
    Action   string
}
```

Then, you'll be able to access all fields in other packages:

```
package taskcontroller

import "entities"

func someFunc() {
    task := entities.Task{
        Id:   123,
        Task: "foo",
    }
    // or
    task.Assignee = "bar"
}
```

Sometimes, though, you may want to limit/control access to fields like this, in which case you can use getters/setters. Again, the same rule applies WRT capitalisation:

```
package entities

// Task as you have it now, with unexported fields
type Task struct {
    Id       int64
    task     string
    assignee string
    deadline string
    action   string
}


// SetAssignee starts with upper-case S, so can be called from other packages
// this method can be used for validation/normalisation/...
// you'll need to add SetX for each field
func (t *Task) SetAssignee(assignee string) error {
    if len(assignee) > 255 {
        return errors.New("assignee too long, max length is 255")
    }
    // assignee is not exported, but using this function its value can be set
    t.assignee = assignee
    return nil
}

// GetAssignee is exported, can be called everywhere
// again, you'll need to implement a GetX for each unexported field
// can be used to return default values, for example
func (t Task) GetAssignee() string {
    if len(t.assignee) == 0 {
        return "none"
    }
    return t.assignee
}

func (t *Task) ToMapAndClear() map[string]interface{} {
    // create a map containing the data
    r := map[string]interface{}{
        "id":       t.Id,
        "task":     t.task,
        "assignee": t.assignee,
        "deadline": t.deadline,
        "action":   t.action,
    }
    // clear all fields. We can call reset from inside the package
    t.reset()
    return r
}

// ExtractMap same function as above, but with defer so it's less verbose
func (t *Task) ExtractMap() map[string]interface{} {
    defer t.reset()
    return map[string]interface{
        "id":       t.Id,
        "task":     t.task,
        "assignee": t.assignee,
        "deadline": t.deadline,
        "action":   t.action,
    }
}

// reset starts with lower-case s, so cannot be called outside of this package
func (t *Task) reset() {
    *t = Task{}
}
```

With these methods, you can use the `entities.Task` type in other packages like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "entities"
)

func main() {
    t := entities.Task{
        Id: 123,
    }
    if err := t.SetAssignee("Benjamin"); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not set assignee: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Task assigned to %s\n", t.GetAssignee()) // works fine
    // does not work
    t.reset() // main package does not have access to reset method
    // this does work - we get the values in a map, and reset gets called internally
    data := t.ExtractMap()
}
```

As you can see, though I can't call `reset` directly outside of the `main` package, I can call exported methods that call `reset` internally.